# Help Needed for parsing FTP files list in c#

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest, ftp-client

I am using this code for getting list of all the files in directory

here webRequestUrl = something.com/directory/

```
FtpWebRequest fwrr = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + webRequestUrl));

fwrr.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
fwrr.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
StreamReader srr = new StreamReader(fwrr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
string str = srr.ReadLine();
ArrayList strList = new ArrayList();
while (str != null)
{
  strList.Add(str);
  str = srr.ReadLine();
}
```

but I am not getting the list of files, but getting some HTML document type lines.

This ftp server is windows based while it is working fine in unix server.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: With ListDirectoryDetails method you will get a UNIX style list of files that you will need to parse. Can you show what you are getting when you say "some HTML document type lines"

Comment: Are you building your own library for ftp? Why don't you just use an existing ftp library?

Comment: This is what I am getting in array list

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<!-- HTML listing generated by Squid 3.0.STABLE13 -->
<!-- Wed, 30 Dec 2009 11:11:48 GMT -->
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>
FTP Directory: ftp://marshal@something.com/directory/
</TITLE>
<STYLE type="text/css"><!--BODY{background-color:#ffffff;font-family:verdana,sans-serif}--></STYLE>

and more... although there are file name of inner files in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when the FTP on a internal machine and I do a ftp://192.168.0.155 - If I try that in IE I get the same HTML result like yours.
I doubt if its happening because of the url. Can you try replacing the url with the IP address (just a wild guess). Even if you are getting HTML, you can strip the unnecessary part and parse the files.

I even tried with a ftp://sub.a.com/somefolder and it worked for me. It seems the browser wraps the HTML around the FTP response because I get different HTML when I opened the FTP site in IE and Chrome.